# JAXB unmarshal is skipping elements with other namespace

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

It's been several years since I've debugged JAXB unmarshalling.  I'm seeing a situation where a valid XML document with namespaces is correctly parsed, but when the code unmarshals the document into an object, some properties within the object are not set, leaving them null.  I can step through code, but once it gets into jaxb unmarshalling, it's very hard to follow what it's doing.  It appears to set instance variables directly on the instances of the JAXB classes (set to FIELD), so I can't set breakpoints in setters to see when (or if) it ever sets particular properties.

I could use some hints on how to get more diagnostics on the unmarshalling process, to see where it might be going wrong.

The XML doc being parsed is relatively simple.  It's a SOAP envelope, and the unmarshalling is done on the first child of the body.

The sub-element in question specifies two namespaces, one the default one for the surrounding element, and another non-default one that is referenced in some of the subelements.  It's actually all the elements that come from the non-default namespace that end up null in the unmarshalled result.  I imagine that's an important clue, but I can't tell what's wrong from that.

With some elisions, the first child of the SOAP body looks like this:

```
<validationResponse xmlns="http://.../ValidationResponse.xsd" xmlns:dm="http://.../DataModel.xsd">
<indicator>true</indicator>
<MatchedAddressResult>
<AddressMatchResult>
<dm:Address>
<dm:Street>
<dm:streetNumber>10000</dm:streetNumber>
<dm:streetName>ELM</dm:streetName>
<dm:streetType>ST</dm:streetType>
</dm:Street>
<dm:Unit>
<dm:type>APT</dm:type>
<dm:value>2033</dm:value>
</dm:Unit>
<dm:city>NOWHERE</dm:city>
<dm:state>TX</dm:state>
<dm:Zip>
<dm:zipCode>11111</dm:zipCode>
<dm:zipCodeExtension>2740</dm:zipCodeExtension>
</dm:Zip>
<dm:county>NOWHERE</dm:county>
</dm:Address>
<dm:cassAddress>
<dm:addressLine>10000 ELM ST APT 2033</dm:addressLine>
<dm:addressLine>NOWHERE TX  11111-2740</dm:addressLine>
</dm:cassAddress>
<dm:addressMatchCode>4S80</dm:addressMatchCode>
<dm:isAddressException>false</dm:isAddressException>
</AddressMatchResult>
</MatchedAddressResult>
<Response>
<dm:code>0</dm:code>
<dm:description>Success</dm:description>
</Response>
</validationResponse>
```

The top of the JAXB class looks like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="ValidateAddressResponseInfo", propOrder={"matchedAddressIndicator", "matchedAddressResult", "response"})
public class ValidationResponseInfo implements Serializable
{
  protected boolean matchedAddressIndicator;
  @XmlElement(name="MatchedAddressResult")
  protected MatchedAddressResult matchedAddressResult;
  @XmlElement(name="Response", required=true)
  protected ResponseInfo response;

  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  @XmlType(name="", propOrder={"exactMatchLocation", "alternativeLocation", "addressMatchResult"})
  public static class MatchedAddressResult
    implements Serializable
  {
    @XmlElement(name="ExactMatchLocation")
    protected ExactMatchLocation exactMatchLocation;

    @XmlElement(name="AlternativeLocation")
    protected AlternativeLocation alternativeLocation;

    @XmlElement(name="AddressMatchResult")
    protected List<AddressValidationResultInfo> addressMatchResult;
```

Again, all the fields that map to the "dm" prefix end up null.  Somehow the unmarshalling isn't mapping those properties.

**Update**:

Here are schema excerpts for the elements in question.

```
  <xs:complexType name='AddressValidationResultInfo'>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name='Address'>
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base='AddressUnrestrictedInfo'>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name='addressType' type='AddressTypeInfo' minOccurs='0'/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='cassAddress' type='CassAddressInfo' minOccurs='0'/>
      <xs:element name='addressMatchCode' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0'>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='addressMatchDescription' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0'>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='addressId' type='FiberServiceAddressIdInfo' minOccurs='0'>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='exchangeCode' type='FiberServiceExchangeCodeInfo' minOccurs='0'>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='isAddressException' type='xs:boolean'>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='addressExceptionCode' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0'>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='addressExceptionDescription' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0'>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='crossBoundaryState' type='CrossBoundaryStateInfo' minOccurs='0'>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='confidence' type='xs:long' minOccurs='0'>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name='AddressUnrestrictedInfo'>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name='attention' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0'/>
      <xs:element name='addressLine1' type='AddressLineInfo' minOccurs='0'>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='addressLine2' type='AddressLineInfo' minOccurs='0'>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='Street' type='AddressStreetUnrestrictedInfo' minOccurs='0'/>
      <xs:element name='Elevation' type='AddressAttributeInfo' minOccurs='0'>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='Structure' type='AddressAttributeInfo' minOccurs='0'>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='Unit' type='AddressAttributeInfo' minOccurs='0'>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='postOfficeBox' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0'/>
      <xs:element name='RuralRoute' minOccurs='0'>
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name='ruralRouteCenterNumber' type='xs:string'/>
            <xs:element name='ruralRouteBoxNumber' type='xs:string'/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='city' type='AddressCityInfo' minOccurs='0'/>
      <xs:element name='state' type='AddressStateInfo' minOccurs='0'/>
      <xs:element name='Zip' type='AddressZipInfo' minOccurs='0'/>
      <xs:element name='country' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0'/>
      <xs:element name='county' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0'>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='countyCode' minOccurs='0'>
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
            <xs:maxLength value='3'/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='urbanizationCode' type='AddressUrbanizationInfo' minOccurs='0'/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name='AddressStreetUnrestrictedInfo'>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name='streetNumberPrefix' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0'>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='streetNumber' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0'>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='streetNumberSuffix' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0'>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='streetDirection' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0'>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='streetName' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0'/>
      <xs:element name='streetType' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0'>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='streetTrailingDirection' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0'>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name='assignedStreetNumber' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0'>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your XSD schemas and generated classes.
Problem is here:
JAXB expects AddressMatchResult as List,
 but there is nothing in XML to satisfy it.
In XML there is an element as

```
<AddressMatchResult>
  <dm:Address>
  <dm:Street>
```

...
So corresponding to AddressMatchResult class must have direct properties as Address, Street and so on.
 Either correct XSD and regenerate JAXB or correct XML according to existing XSD

Comment: How would you suggest I "correct XML according to existing XSD"?

Comment: Hi David, question is how you get null values for thos dm:elements (i.e. Address, Street etc?

Comment: looking at JAXB class I assume it should be something like that: addressMatchResult.getAddressValidationResultInfo.get(0).getAddress()  If it is you may try to wrap all you have in AddressMatchResult into &lt;AddressValidationResultInfo&gt; tag

Answer (score 0):

> It's actually all the elements that come from the non-default
>   namespace that end up null in the unmarshalled result. I imagine
>   that's an important clue, but I can't tell what's wrong from that.

Indeed, it is probably.

Is xmlns referenced for dm prexif in your soap message  is which is declared in xsd ?
Don"t hesitate to show xsd files, it may be helpful.

> Again, all the fields that map to the "dm" prefix end up null. Somehow
>   the unmarshalling isn't mapping those properties.

It gives the impression that the namespace is not recognized during unmarshalling.
Namespace is not precising in jaxb elements. So I suppose it is declared in package-info.java files.

Can you check that the namespace used for element with dm prefix is which is expected and it is located in the suitable package:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema (
    namespace = "yourRealNamespaceForDn",
    elementFormDefault=javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
)
```

If all is ok, another other way to progress in your problem resolving would to isolate it by writing a simple unit test which uses jaxb unserialization with the xml you extracted in input and your expected created object in output. 
Try to play with namespace declaration in your jaxb element by specifying namespace attribute such as :

```
@XmlType(namespace="yourNamespace", name="", propOrder={"exactMatchLocation", "alternativeLocation", "addressMatchResult"})
  public static class MatchedAddressResult ...
```

Comment: I can't modify the JAXB classes.  Note that I did step through the parser, and I saw it parse the "xmlns:dm" attribute and store the info for that namespace.  I can't tell what you mean by "Can you check that the namespace used ...".

Comment: So I realized you were referring to checking the contents of the associated "package-info" files. I was able to verify that the namespaces specified for both ValidationResponseInfo and AddressValidationResultInfo matches when I'm specifying in the XML.

Comment: Can you post fragment of XSD definition for MatchedAddressResult, its type as well as for AddressValidationResultInfo?

Comment: BTW if you have XSD you can generate JAXB classes over - in separate project just for testing purposes.